# Getting User Input and storing it to a pointer array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm creating a petty cash fund system program for my project in Programming and it involves me using pointer arrays to simulate tables.

I've created a portion where the user is requested to input additional data to append to my current table however my executable file crashes when it gets to the part where the user is asked for input (in my case it would be the getline(cin,my2dArrayPointerHere[][]) )

Can anyone point to me what I've done wrong? I also tried using regular non-pointer string arrays but I still get the same crash.

I am using the std namespace btw. Also please ignore some of the comments. Those are intended for my groupmates who may have questions on my part of code.

```
                int numTrans;
                char tempChar[1000];
                double tempHolder;
                string **tempDataHolder;

                cout<<"Input number of transactions to add: ";
                cin>>numTrans;


                tempDataHolder = new string*[numTrans]; //pointer array 
                for(i=0;i<numTrans;i++)
                tempDataHolder[i] = new string[col];

                cout<<"\nPlease input the following data as necessary: \n";
                for(ir=0; ir<numTrans;ir++)
                {
                    cout<<"Date Requested: "; //This may seem unnecessary but some companies require paper 
                                          //documentation aside from a system to approve petty cash
                                          //and sometimes the accounting staff has too much to do to 
                                          //perform data entry jobs in realtime such as this
                    getline(cin,tempDataHolder[ir][col]);
                    cout<<"Person Requesting Funds: ";
                    getline(cin,tempDataHolder[ir][col+1]);
                    cout<<"Person who approved request: ";
                    getline(cin,tempDataHolder[ir][col+2]);
                    cout<<"Amount Requested: Php. ";
                    cin>>tempHolder; //temp double number to properly format money
                    ostringstream convert; 
                    convert<<tempHolder;
                    tempDataHolder[ir][col+3] = convert.str();
                    cout<<"Particulars: ";
                    getline(cin,tempDataHolder[ir][col+4]);
                    tempDataHolder[ir][col+5] = " "; //initialized to empty space because 
                    tempDataHolder[ir][col+6] = " "; //data has not yet been retrieved 
                    tempDataHolder[ir][col+7] = " "; //through liquidation
                    tempDataHolder[ir][col+8] = " ";
                    tempDataHolder[ir][col+9] = "false";                    
                }
                tableSize = deterSize(curFileName) + (numTrans*col); //this will ensure the next table will house all new elements as well
                readCurFile(curFileName, tableSize);
                displayCurTable(tableSize);


                delete tempDataHolder;
```

Comment: Wonder how much time and headache could be saved if teachers really taught C++, not C with classes!

Comment: In the first dimension, you iterate in range `[0,numTrans]` which coincides with the allocated size. In the second dimension, you iterate in range `[col, col+9]`, while you only have allocated `[0,col]`. Why is this so? May be the reason for the crash.

Comment: Omg. I see the reason why... ugh. Here I was thinking maybe I did something wrong with syntaxes but it was logical! I was taught to always use variables inside the indices that I forgot that I didn't need an index for my column. Thanks guys!

Comment: "I was taught to always use variables inside the indices" - that sounds almost like nonsense. Use whatever the program logic tells you to use as the array index. It's perfectly valid to use constant indices in a certain range. (Though when the range is growing large, it may be time to rethink the design into a struct or something similar.)

Comment: Thats the plan, I can already do it but I prefer to wait until we touch the subject (I had prior knowledge to c++ but I'm so rusty that I think waiting for the professor's lesson would help me better).

Answer (score 0):

You allocate 'col' string elements in 'tempDataHolder[i]=new string[col]' but when you read user inputs, you use 'col', 'col+1', etc. It means you try to write to array indices that are greater than 'col'.